# How to name a file for download on Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, firefox, attachment

The following headers work on IE but not on FF

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/csv" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage"%>
<% Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=report.csv;attachment"); %>
```

In FF the suggested name in FF appears as "report" without the extension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently using code that looks like this:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"data.csv\"");
```

In my daily work - and that works just fine. Also are you sure this is not your OS or anything that has the "Hide extensions for known file types"-option enabled? (I know Windows have this option and it drives me crazy)

Comment: Maybe because he linked the documentation

Comment: Possibly, idk... I *think* the solution is to use the quotes (being escaped) but I honestly don't know - I posted this as I knew it worked for me, I have no link to documentation or anything as it is code I created months and months ago and have used ever since without any issues.

Answer (score 4):

`filename` is just an parameter of [*Content-Dispostion*](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1). So you have to swap both:

```
<% Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=report.csv"); %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently i faced this issue too, **finally got the solution**

To make It work correctly in firefox, make sure in file name Quotes are placed correctly and with no Spaces in file name

so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393647/response-content-type-as-csv) is the sample example to do basic test

**This will work:**

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ "MyOrders"+ "_Date_"
+DateTime.Now.ToString("d")+".csv");
```

**This also will work**:

```
string myfilename = "MyOrders" + "_Date_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + ".csv";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", 
myfilename));

//here you can check using the break point,weather you are using any extra quotes in filename
```

**This will not work in firefox**

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+ "MyOrders"+ "_Date_"
+DateTime.Now+".csv");

// because in DateTime.Now there is spaces in Time, Seconds , so firefox downloads file not 
//as csv but downloads it as File , may be a binary file or unknown file type
```

References used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5347297/2218697) , [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1154144/2218697), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817292/2218697) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983604/2218697)

Thanks to all whose post's helped somehow.

Hope it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

This question about CSV generation helped me when I needed to implement CSV generation and download: [How do I best generate a CSV (comma-delimited text file) for download with ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44194/how-do-i-best-generate-a-csv-comma-delimited-text-file-for-download-with-asp-ne)

Comment: thank you for the post, it helped to solve an issue with firefox [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32373057/2218697) is the solution

Answer (score 0):

`try "attachment; filename=\"report.csv\""` (i.e. with quoted filename)