# Firefox will not download this file as a CSV

Tags: java, servlets, csv

I have tried everything I can think of.  I have changed the mime type 100 times.  Changed the headers 400 times.  I've looked through stack over flow a dozen times.  This works fine in Chrome.  Soon as I go to download in Firefox it thinks it's a xlsx file, or a binary file.  It even opens as an xlsx but it doesn't think it's a csv so the columns aren't seperated.  If I save the file(instead of just hit open) it doesn't even put the extension on.  I haven't even got to IE yet so this is kind of worrying me.

```
    mime mapping
   <mime-mapping>
        <extension>csv</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-excel</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

I've tried text/csv, application/csv, application/binary, application/octet-stream.

```
public void doDownloadFile() {

            PrintWriter out = null;

            try {

                String fileName = selectedPkgLine.getShortname() + ".csv";

                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
                HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

                response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
                response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
                response.setContentType(request.getServletContext().getMimeType(fileName));
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + "");
                response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

                out = response.getWriter();
                CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(out);

                List<PkgLoad> pkgLoadList = pkgLoadService.findBetweenDates(selectedPkgLine, startDate, endDate);

                List<String[]> stringList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
                stringList.clear();

                String[] header = {
                    "pkg_load_id",
                    "time_stamp",
                    "ounces",
                    "revolutions",
                    "wrap_spec_id",
                    "pkg_line_id"
                };

                stringList.add(header);

                for (PkgLoad pkgLoad : pkgLoadList) {

                    String[] string = {
                        pkgLoad.getPkgLoadId().toString(),
                        pkgLoad.getTimeStamp().toString(),
                        pkgLoad.getOunces().toString(),
                        pkgLoad.getRevolutions().toString(),
                        pkgLoad.getWrapSpecId().getWrapSpecId().toString(),
                        pkgLoad.getPkgLineId().getPkgLineId().toString()
                    };
                    stringList.add(string);
                }

                response.setHeader("Content-length", String.valueOf(stringList.size()));


                writer.writeAll(stringList);
                out.flush();

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ViewLines.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        }
```

Thanks for any help.

Safari, Opera and Chrome work fine.  Haven't tried IE.

## ****EDIT****

Ok this entire time it was a spacing issue.  My file name was "file name.csv" and this works in every browser except firefox.  Soon as I put my file name to "filename.csv with no spaces it downloaded it find.  I didn't notice that when it was downloading it was only downloading the first part of the name before the space.  Good luck!

Comment: You should try it with IE and see what result you get there. Maybe that tells you more about the problem you have with Firefox.

Comment: Note that the `<mime-mapping>` is only been used when the resource is been served from public webcontent by a direct link/call or when you use `ServletContext#getMimeType()`. It is irrelevant in this particular purpose where you serve the response and set the `Content-Type` header yourself.

Comment: Yes I understand.  I was just trying whatever I could do.  This particular code works in IE8.  It sees it as a csv and I can save it and open it.  I don't know what is wrong with firefox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok this entire time it was a spacing issue. My file name was "file name.csv" and this works in every browser except firefox. Soon as I put my file name to "filename.csv with no spaces it downloaded it find. I didn't notice that when it was downloading it was only downloading the first part of the name before the space.

In the future make sure the filename has a single quote around it in the header.  This will allow Firefox to download it correctly(without stripping off anything past the space) if you need a space the file name.

Good luck!

Comment: Anybody coming to this issue now: see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filenames_with_spaces_are_truncated_upon_download. The real issue is that you should have Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename with spaces".

Comment: @NateBundy's comment is correct.  You have escape double quotes around the filename if your header is in a double quoted string.

Comment: thank you for the post, it helped to solve an issue with firefox [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32373057/2218697) is the solution

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue in PHP and found adding double quotes for the file name fixes the problem.

```
 response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + \"");
```

Answer (score 5):

The content type text/csv is correct, but you should also add an charset encoding:

```
response.setHeader("Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
```

But what the hell is this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
response.setHeader("Content-length", String.valueOf(stringList.size()));
```

Remove that headers! The content length is in bytes. Do not try to calculate it by yourself. It is definitly wrong in this example! A Mime-Type with major type `text` is not binary!

Comment: Still does not work.  Firefox keeps stripping the csv off the end.  IE8 works in this case.  If I change the content-type to 

.xls application/excel
.xls application/vnd.ms-excel
.xls application/x-excel
.xls application/x-msexcel

it puts an xls or xlsx on the end.

Comment: Please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848019/why-php-script-does-not-generate-csv-file-in-firefox/39848402) Need help

Answer (score 1):

Add the content-type header with value text/csv

```
response.setHeader("Content-type: text/x-csv");
```

Comment: `text/csv` should also suffice.

Comment: Doesn't work.  Same thing.  Firefox sees it as a filename with no extension.  If I add application/vnd.ms-excel as the content type it sees it as an excel(xlsx) file even though its a .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
Response.ContentType = "text/csv; charset=utf-8";

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in Java/JSP but are you sure this is correct for text/csv?
response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

Did you try commenting out this? In PHP I will simply echo/print the CSV preceded with headers content-type headers and disposition type.