# firefox cannot download csv file

Tags: php, csv, firefox

I'm trying to generate and then by default download csv file using php script. I have code which is working fine in chrome and internet explorer but the same script does not works in firefox. In firefox script does not generating csv file properly. Following are the script

```
require('core.php');
$master = new db();
$s = $master->getRecords();
function array2csv(array &$array)
{
   if (count($array) == 0) {
     return null;
   }
   ob_start();
   $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
   fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($array)));
   foreach ($array as $row) {
      fputcsv($df, $row);
   }
   fclose($df);
   return ob_get_clean();
}

function download_send_headers($filename) {

     // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");


    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}
download_send_headers(site_title .' '. date("d M Y") . ".csv");
echo array2csv($s);
die();
```

**HTML and JS**

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return exportUser();">Export to CSV</a> 

function exportUser(){ 
        $.ajax({
        url: 'get_csv.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function() {
            window.location = 'get_csv.php';
        }
    });
}
```

I also attached a screenshot for understanding.[image]

Comment: *"In firefox script does not generating csv file properly."* ... in what way?

Comment: @CD001 the same code is working fine in chrome and IE, it is generating the csv file and downloading but the same script does not work in firefox that's it.

Comment: Doesn't generate the CSV file at all (doesn't pull up a download dialogue box) or generates it onscreen rather than as a download or generates it incorrectly somehow so it's not valid CSV?

Comment: @CD001 yes exactly `generates it incorrectly somehow so it's not valid CSV`, thanks for well explaination

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Instead of which ?

Comment: You can try removing application/download and adding that and see if it works

Comment: The way i do it is, i have a hidden iFrame on my page. I then set the url of that iFrame to my report php script. The report script is the one that generates the report.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event to your js function

function exportUser(event) will do it

Comment: Please explain it, i didn't understand

Comment: You currently call your function like this "function exportUser()", but because it is Mozilla Firefox it doesn't work cause you aren't sending any events. You need to call your function like this "function exportUser(event)"