# How to get the current date without the time?

Tags: c#, .net

I am able to get date and time using:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

How can I get the current date and time separately in the DateTime format itself?

I am not using the DateTime picker dialog box in ASP.NET (C#).

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Well, you can get just today's date as a `DateTime` using the [`Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) property:

```
 DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
```

or more generally, you can use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property. For example, if you wanted the UTC date you could use:

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
```

It's not very clear whether that's what you need or not though... if you're just looking to *print* the date, you can use:

```
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("d"));
```

or use an explicit format:

```
Console.WriteLine(dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

See more about [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date/time format strings. Depending on your situation you may also want to specify the culture.

If you want a more expressive date/time API which allows you to talk about dates separately from times, you might want to look at the [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project which I started. It's not ready for production just yet, but we'd love to hear what you'd like to do with it...

Comment: -> Hi. Will UtcNow.Date work for all countries. I want the current date of the current locality. I know to convert full datetime to current timezone. But what if I truncate the time part. I am from India and my friend in california. For me it is 9:30 AM Sunday IST now. For my friend, it is 09:00 PM saturday in Los Angeles now.

Comment: @Thameem: Well it will give the *UTC* date regardless, which is why I recommended it for that scenario. The UTC date doesn't depend on where you are, because it uses UTC instead of the local time zone.

Comment: So, in order to get the local date. I have to get utc.now, convert it to local time and truncate time part or just read the date. Understood. Thanks

Comment: @Thameem: Yes, or you can just use `DateTime.Today` *if* the system time zone is the one you're interested in.

Answer (score 47):

See, here you can get only date by passing a format string.
You can get a different date format as per your requirement as given below for current date:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

> **Result :** "9/1/2015"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("M-d-yyyy");
```

> **Result :** "9-1-2015"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

> **Result :** "2015-09-01"

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

> **Result :** "2015-09-01 09:20:10"

For more details take a look at [MSDN reference for Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 39):

Use [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) property. It will return date component of `DateTime.Now`. It is equivalent of `DateTime.Now.Date`.
Starting from .NET 6 you might also consider using [`DateOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0) and [`TimeOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeonly?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 29):

Current Time  :

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

Current Date  :

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no built-in date-only type in .NET.

The convention is to use a `DateTime` with the time portion set to midnight.

The static [`DateTime.Today`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx) property will give you today's date.

Answer (score 10):

You can use following code to get the date and time separately.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string date = now.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];
string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
```

You can also, check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

As of .Net 6 you can use:

```
 var dateOnly = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dateonly?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 2):

In `.Net6`, you can use the new `DateOnly` Type :

```
DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Today)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
txtdate.Text = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need separately date parts like (day, Month, Year)

> DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

Will not work for your case. You can get date separately so you don't need variable `today` to be as a `DateTime`Type, so lets just give `today` variable `int` Type because the day is only int. So today is 10 March 2020 then the result of

> int today = DateTime.Today.Day;
>
> int month = DateTime.Today.Month;
>
> int year = DateTime.Today.Year;
>
> MessageBox.Show(today.ToString()+ " - this is day. "+month.ToString()+
>   " - this is month. " + year.ToString() + " - this is year");

would be "**10** - this is day. **3** - this is month. **2020** - this is year"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` like so:

```
var test = $"<b>Date of this report:</b> {DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Code for Day:

```
lblyear.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("DD");
```

Code for Month:

```
lblyear.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
```

Code for Month name (Feb):

```
lblyear.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM");
```

Code for Year:

```
lblyear.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("YYYY");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string now = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
Console.WriteLine(now);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -2):

for month

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
```

for day

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");
```

for year

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```