# Current date without time

Tags: c#

How can I get the current date but without the time? I am trying to convert the date from the "dd.mm.yyyy" format to "yyyy-MM-dd", because `DateTime.Now` returns the time too, I get an error (`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.) when I try to do the following.

```
string test = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: You're taking the current date and time, converting it to a string, parsing it and then converting it to a different string?

Comment: Converting to one string format, parsing that and then converting to another string format doesn't make sense. Why not simply do `string test = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current date without the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817266/how-to-get-the-current-date-without-the-time)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
String test = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyy");
```

Answer (score 58):

Use the [Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property: Gets the date component of this instance.

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
var date = dateAndTime.Date;
```

variable `date` contain the date and the time part will be 00:00:00.

or

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

or

[DateTime.ToShortDateString Method-](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString ());
```

Comment: I prefer this method

Answer (score 25):

Have you tried

```
DateTime.Now.Date
```

Comment: This isn't actually needed.  You can convert a `DateTime` with both a date and a time to a string that has just the date.  You don't need to do this first.

Comment: it seems to answer the first question: "How can I get the current date but without the time?"

Comment: And yet from the context of the question it's clear he wants the result as a string, so you're still going to be calling `ToString` on your `DateTime`, and you'll need to have it provide the exact same formatting that a `DateTime` object with a time would need to supply.  In other words, adding `.Date` gains nothing.  That's why we read past the first sentence when answering questions.

Comment: I understand something different. It seems we are also people: the person asking the question is a she. :)

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  A date object without the current time.  This is better than DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyy.MM.dd")) .   Also see below, DateTime.Today does the same thing.

Answer (score 11):

```
String test = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 7):

it should be as simple as

```
DateTime.Today
```

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
string datetime = DateTime.Today.ToString();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get current UTC date without time. 
`string currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in several answers already that have been already given, you can use `ToShorDateString()`:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

However, you may be a bit blocked if you also want to use the culture as a parameter. In this case you can use the `ToString()` method with the `"d"` format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   var mydtn = DateTime.Today;
   var myDt = mydtn.Date;return myDt.ToString("d", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need exact your example, you should add format to ToString()

```
    string test = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy"), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

But it's better to use straight formatting:

```
    string test = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Comment: You shouldn't be converting a date to a string, parsing it, and then turning it into a string again.  Just turn it into the right string to begin with.

Comment: I know, but he asked, why he gets exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: If you're going to do that you should also solve the problem appropriately, in addition to explaining how to get the incorrect approach to work.