# What does DateTime now = DateTime.Now; do in C#?

Tags: c#

I found out how to get the current date and time as variables (right?) in C# thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817266/get-current-date-only-in-c-sharp?newreg=d5fcc209e3f7438dbb3ba1c51549a85b) with the code

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string date = now.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];
string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
```

However I'm not sure what the first line does. After some thinking I suppose it calls the current date and time data from the computer and applies/tells it to the program.

By the way, I'm a noob at programming and new to C#.

Comment: It is a static property so it requires no instance. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This should help you understand what is going on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first line

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

takes the current time, and stores it in a variable. The reason it's done is to make sure that subsequent calls of `GetDateTimeFormats` are performed on a variable representing the same time. If you call `DateTime.Now` several times, you may get a different time each time that you make a call.

For example, if you do

```
string date = DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats('d')[0];
string time = DateTime.Now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
```

very close to midnight, the `date` and `time` portions may belong to different dates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does exactly what you think it does.

You created a variable called `now` (type `DateTime`) and assigned it to `DateTime.Now` which is a special static property of `DateTime` that:

> Gets a DateTime object that is set to the current date and time on
>   this computer, expressed as the local time.

([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

So you have the date and time that line of code was run stored off in the `now` variable. Simple as that.