# Can we input different date inputs while running the Automation script each time

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2. We have a requirement of creating a module with unique date so that i cannot create a module with already used date.So when i am running the script , i have to pass different date each time.How we can choose random date in automation.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using chancejs.

```
var Chance = require('chance'),
    chance = new Chance();

    console.log(chance.integer({ min: -2, max: 2 }));
```

would return either -2, -1, 0, 1, or 2.

Please take a look at the chancejs homepage http://chancejs.com/

Below example gives a data between these two years

```
    var Chance = require('chance');
    var chance = new Chance();

    let bounds = {
        min: chance.date({ year: 1983 }),
        max: chance.date({ year: 1989 })
    }

    let date = chance.date(bounds)
    console.log(date);
```

I got `1987-01-21T19:31:32.851Z`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually i need to generate a future date of format "MM-DD-YYYY" and pass that date into a date field. i have tried with below code by passing a start&end date to a function.but sometimes it gives same date even though it is random.
moment(new Date(start.getTime() + (Math.floor(Math.random()*3 ) + 1  ) * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
Can we do this using chancejs?

Comment: Edited the answer with date in chancejs

Comment: Great..Can we pass a min&max year to this, to generate a random date in between that 2 years.

Comment: mention the maximum and minimum year

Answer (score 0):

1.Random dates in JAVA 
[Generate random date of birth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth)

2. if you are using the Excel as data provider 
   Use the Excel formula's like

   =today();
   =now();
3. if you are using java or other languages

   - use

     SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyyHH:mm:ss");
     Date date = new Date();
4. C#
   [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817266/get-current-date-only-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985392/generate-random-date-of-birth)

Answer (score 0):

[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) is a good option that allows you to set time easily off the current time.
**Examples:**

```
moment.format('MM/DD/YYYY'); //gives you current date in mm/dd/yyyy format
moment.format('MM-DD-YYYY'); //current date in mm-dd-yyyy format
moment.add('5','days').format('MM/DD/YYYY'); gives you date 5 days from now
```