# How do I check if a certain date has passed in C#?

Tags: c#

How would I go about checking if a certain date has passed?

The way this would work is; the program has 3 integers stored
a day, for example: '28' a month: '3' and a year: '2019'.

How would I check if '28-3-2019' has already passed?

The program would return false if the current date is 27-3-2019
and should return true if the current date is 29-3-2019.

The code would be something like:

```
var date = 28-3-2019

if (date.Passed == true)
{
    //do something
}
```

The date could also be split into 3 ints ofcourse.

Comment: `if(new DateTime(year, month, day) > DateTime.Today)` ?

Comment: @RubensFarias that would be, date hasn't happened yet.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817266/get-current-date-only

Comment: @RubensFarias Thanks!! it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);

if(date < DateTime.Now)
{
    // date has passed. 
}
else
{
   // the date is in the future
}
```