# Not recognized valid date date time

Tags: c#

Need to convert `08-13-2022 10:27 PM` to `08/12/2022`.

This is my code:

```
 DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(String.Format("MM/dd/yyyy", row["POSTING_DATE"]));
 row["POSTING_DATE"] = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

But I get this error:

> not recognized valid date date time

Comment: share the data you have in row["POSTING_DATE"], in 1st line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current date without the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6817266/how-to-get-the-current-date-without-the-time)

Comment: You dont need to create a string and parse it to create a DateTime variable.  You can create them directly.

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime(date)` is a bit pointless when `date` is already a `DateTime`.

Comment: It's also a bit pointless doing a `DateTime.Parse` on a string create using `String.Format` on a value which was a `DateTime` anyway.

Comment: And finally, your call to `String.Format` is not valid.

Comment: You need to learn to debug.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0) method as follows:

```
string POSTING_DATE = "08-13-2022 10:27 PM";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(POSTING_DATE, "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm tt",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
POSTING_DATE = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(POSTING_DATE);//prints 08/13/2022
```

Comment: Can you also include why the OP's code was wrong?